# Display time with push button interrupt Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I need to write a code that contains an interval loop but contains a push button interrupt that displays RTC values when activated. I have found a way to individually do each task i.e change pushbutton state, loop in intervals, display RTC value but I cannot seem to combine them and create a working. If someone can provide links or an explanation on how to accomplish this I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not use** `delay(interval);` in your main loop, you can run as many tasks in parallel as you want. Understand the BlinkWithoutDelay sample, and try to extend it to two leds blinking independently. Or read a button while blinking.

And push button and interrupt does not go together well, BTW.
You even might add a *small* `delay(2);` to slow down polling the button pin.
This is usually fine for the other parallel running tasks and implements a very simple debounce mechanism.